# Using a Headless CMS to send email newsletter?

Tags: email, headless-cms

I'm exploring if I can use a Headless CMS to manage the content for a regular email newsletter. I havn't discovered any tools that will allow me to quickly build this out.

Keen to know if anyone has tried to build this and what their stack or setup is? My ideal process:

1. Create new post in Headless CMS such as Sanity to be published on
   certain date.
2. Content is compiled into a HTML newsletter
   automatically (an email builder which allows you to output certain
   content where you want it including title, body etc would be
   perfect).
3. Email is scheduled for send and ultimately sent.

**Note**: A Headless CMS allows you to 'decoupled from the presentation layer' meaning that the content is front-end agnostic, meaning that your content is raw and can be published anywhere, through any framework.